# sort posts that have the largest number of similar tags

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know that the following code can select each post in Post model that has at least one of tags by id:1,2,3

```
$ids = [1,2,3];
$posts = Post::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($ids) {
     $query = $query->whereIn('id', $ids);
})->get();
```

output:

```
Collection {
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => Post {
      ...
      #attributes: array: [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'title',
        'content' => 'content'
      ]
     ...
     #relations: array:1 [▼
        "tags" => Collection {#828 ▼
          #items: array:3 [▼
            0 => Tag {#806 ▶}
            1 => Tag {#807 ▶}
            2 => Tag {#808 ▶}
          ]
        }
     ]
     ...
```

Now, My question is how can I sort this posts that have the largest number of similar tags. I mean, posts that have more similar tags in my $ids have more priority, first posts that have all 3 tags then 2 and finally 1 of the tags in my list?

Comment: Can you please post your output?

Comment: this a list of a collection that has at least one of tag ids

Comment: $collection = collect([
        ['name' => 'Desk', 'colors' => ['Black', 'Mahogany']],
        ['name' => 'Chair', 'colors' => ['Black']],
        ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'colors' => ['Red', 'Beige', 'Brown']],
    ]);

    $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
        return count($product['colors']);
    });

    dd($sorted->values()->all());

Comment: May be help you above example

Comment: @SachinAghera - You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = collect([
        ['name' => 'Desk', 'colors' => ['Black', 'Mahogany']],
        ['name' => 'Chair', 'colors' => ['Black']],
        ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'colors' => ['Red', 'Beige', 'Brown']],
    ]);

    $sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
        return count($product['colors']);
    });

    dd($sorted->values()->all());
```

Comment: thank u, But If you look at my code Post model have m2m relation to Tags, and I haven't such form of data

Comment: So can you post your output?

Comment: It is a little complicating, I want posts that have more similar tags in my $ids have more priority but by your answer posts that have more tag become earlier not necessarily more similar tags in my $ids ...